# Por que o servidor web não encontra minha rota?

Tags: laravel, htaccess, apache

Fiz o *upload* de um sistema em Laravel chamado **android_api** no servidor da hostgator, e configurei no arquivo public.

Até a página principal ele funciona, onde aparece o Laravel 5, porém quando coloco a rota que criei, ele mostra pagina não encontrada.

Publiquei na raiz do meu servidor:

```
-> raiz
      |_ android_api
      |_ public_html
             |_ android_api (que é a pasta public)
                  |_ index.php
```

Vocês podem ver [aqui](http://gysacakes.com.br/android_api/) como encontra normal o Laravel, mas se coloco a rota que criei [/listaService](http://gysacakes.com.br/android_api/listaService), dá página não encontrada.

Minha rota está assim:

```
Route::get('/listaService', "GeralController@getServices" );
```

Localmente funciona.

Vi que tenho que configurar um *Virtual Host* lá no servidor da Hostgator, mas não achei esse local.

Meu `.htaccess` está assim:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /android_api

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: O seu ```RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]``` não teria que ser ```RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ public/$1 [L,R=301]``` ? Veja se isso te ajuda: http://www.codegeo.com.br/2013/03/utilizando-htaccess-para-hospedar-uma.html

Comment: Só que esse htaccess era do projeto, mas adicionei no htaccess do sevidor essas configurações que você indicou e funcionou. Pode adicionar como resposta. Obrigado

Comment: Show de bola então. Também já tive um problema parecido no passado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atualmente seu RewriteRule está assim:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Como o arquivo index.php mapeado pelo servidor como arquivo padrão de busca e carregamento fica dentro do diretório **public**, sendo assim basta fazer a seguinte alteração:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ public/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Para mais informações: http://www.codegeo.com.br/2013/03/utilizando-htaccess-para-hospedar-uma.html